# My jQuery takes width and height of element before it loads contents

Tags: jquery, css

I have made script that center div on center of browser window, and my problem is here:

The script takes a width and height of overlay_window before it loads content, so it centres div like for 1px x 1px element, right after this it loads contents and I don`t know how to prevent this.

Can someone help me?

Here the code:

```
$(document).ready( function(){      
    $('.cod').click(function() {
        var div_name = $(this).attr('id');      
        $('.overlay_window').load('/templates/' + div_name + '_template.php');
        var div_width = $('#'+div_name+'-overlay').width();
        var div_height = $('#'+div_name+'-overlay').height();
        $('.overlay_window').css("width", ""+div_width+"px")
        $('.overlay_window').css("height", ""+div_height+"px")
        var div2_width = $('.overlay_window').width();
        var div2_height = $('.overlay_window').height();
        var window_width = $(window).width();
        var window_height = $(window).height();         
        var widthoffset = (window_width - div2_width) / 2;  
        var heightoffset = (window_height - div2_height) / 2;   
        $('.overlay_window').css("left", "" + (widthoffset-div_width) + "px");
        $('.overlay_window').css("top", "" + (heightoffset-div_height) + "px");
        $('.overlay_background').fadeIn();
        $('.overlay_window').fadeIn();  
    });
});
```

and CSS:

```
div.overlay_window{
    background:#ffffff;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:200;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment, dont see you fix width inside a click callback function

Comment: @Epsil0neR: your suggested edit was very poor. Please don't only look at formatting, but also at English. Obvious spelling mistakes like "ive", "centre", "idk", etc needs to be edited as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your style changes when data is loaded from [.load(url, completed)](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function. You simple asked to load page and while it loadings, you make your style changes.

```
$(document).ready( function(){    
    $('.cod').click(function() {
       var div_name = $(this).attr('id');
       $('.overlay_window').load('/templates/' + div_name + '_template.php'**, function(){
          var div_width = $('#'+div_name+'-overlay').width();
          var div_height = $('#'+div_name+'-overlay').height();
          $('.overlay_window').css("width", ""+div_width+"px")
          $('.overlay_window').css("height", ""+div_height+"px")
          var div2_width = $('.overlay_window').width();
          var div2_height = $('.overlay_window').height();
          var window_width = $(window).width();
          var window_height = $(window).height();
          var widthoffset = (window_width - div2_width) / 2;  
          var heightoffset = (window_height - div2_height) / 2;   
          $('.overlay_window').css("left", "" + (widthoffset-div_width) + "px");
          $('.overlay_window').css("top", "" + (heightoffset-div_height) + "px");
          $('.overlay_background, .overlay_window').fadeIn();
       });
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try writing the Click function outside $(document).ready . If it still doesn't work
 enclose the click function within

```
$(#someID).is(:visible){
//your code here
}
```

add id="someID" in your div

Hope things work :)

Comment: That won`t work because he makes changes with styles while page is loading and at that moment div is empty, so its width and height is 1px x 1px.